# pandas how to efficiently split large dataframe into two sets with a grouped condition on datetime

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, performance, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a large dataframe (~40 million rows) and I want to split it into two parts. Column `'group'` indicates to which group the sample belongs and column `'date'` which date the sample occurred. In the following test case, there can be multiple equal samples, but in the original set, this is not the case. Further, in the original data, there are three columns.
Now, if the latest date of one group is older or equal than `'2017-01-30'`, I want to put the whole group to `s1` otherwise to `s2`.

The code below does what it should, but it is very slow. Do you have an idea, how I can speed up the process? Do you know, why this approach is so slow?
The line `df['split'] = grouped['date'].transform(lambda x: x.max() < date_)` is the bottleneck.
Thanks for your help.

```
from random import randint
import numpy as np
import time
import pandas as pd

length = int(1e5)

bimonthly_days = np.arange(0, 30)
base_date = np.datetime64('2017-01-01')
random_date = base_date + np.random.choice(bimonthly_days)

groups = np.random.randint(1, int(2e4), length)
dates = np.array([base_date + np.random.choice(bimonthly_days) for _ in range(length)], dtype='datetime64[ns]')

df = pd.DataFrame({'group': groups, 'date': dates})

grouped = df.groupby('group')
date_ = np.datetime64('2017-01-30')

start_time = time.process_time()
df['split'] = grouped['date'].transform(lambda x: x.max() < date_)
dif = time.process_time() - start_time
print(f" elapsed time: {dif}")

s1 = df[df['split'] == 1].drop(columns=['split'])
s2 = df[df['split'] == 0].drop(columns=['split'])
```

Output:

```
elapsed time: 12.923806
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faster is create `Series` with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and then compare only once, like compare each group separately. Also you can create new mask instead column for comparing, and for invert mask use `~`:

```
mask = grouped['date'].transform('max') < date_

s1 = df[mask]
s2 = df[~mask]
```

**Performance**:

```
np.random.seed(10)
length = int(1e5)

bimonthly_days = np.arange(0, 30)
base_date = np.datetime64('2017-01-01')
random_date = base_date + np.random.choice(bimonthly_days)

groups = np.random.randint(1, int(2e4), length)
dates = np.array([base_date + np.random.choice(bimonthly_days) for _ in range(length)], dtype='datetime64[ns]')

df = pd.DataFrame({'group': groups, 'date': dates})


In [219]: %timeit df.groupby('group')['date'].transform('max') < np.datetime64('2017-01-30')
9.81 ms ± 645 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [220]: %timeit df.groupby('group')['date'].transform(lambda x: x.max() < np.datetime64('2017-01-30'))
9.05 s ± 159 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
start_time = time.process_time() df.loc[:,'split'] = df.groupby('group').date.transform('max') dif = time.process_time() - start_time print(f" elapsed time: {dif}")

s1 = df[df.split < date_] s2 = df[df.split >= date_]

 elapsed time: 0.01961299999999966
```

With your method my time is:

```
elapsed time: 6.9499130000000005
```

Comment: Same like my answer.